# Android on button click App crashes

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

In Main Activity  i'm using Intent as

```
btnlocate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
              Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, gotomap.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
                 MainActivity.this.finish();
        }           
    });
```

In gotomap.xml Im using fragment in layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

gotomap.java

```
public class gotomap extends Activity {
    public gotomap(){}
    getcoordinates loc;
    double lati,longi;
       private GoogleMap googleMap;

       @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          loc = new getcoordinates(this);               //getlocation

            if(loc.canGetLocation())            
            {                
               lati = loc.getLatitude();
               longi = loc.getLongitude();
              Toast.makeText(this, "Your Location is - \nLat: " + lati + "\nLong: " + longi, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
          }
            final LatLng locate = new LatLng(lati ,longi);

          setContentView(R.layout.gotomap);

          try {
             if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().
                findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
             }

          catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
       }
    }
```

log

```
  02-02 10:16:13.986: I/Process(30530): Sending signal. PID: 30530 SIG: 9
02-02 10:16:17.883: V/Monotype(30591): SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.example.locato
02-02 10:16:17.885: V/Monotype(30591):     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
02-02 10:16:17.891: V/Monotype(30591): SetAppTypeFace- try to flip, app = com.example.locato
02-02 10:16:17.891: V/Monotype(30591):     Typeface getFontPathFlipFont - systemFont = default#default
02-02 10:16:17.943: D/OpenGLRenderer(30591): Render dirty regions requested: true
02-02 10:16:17.963: D/Atlas(30591): Validating map...
02-02 10:16:18.041: I/OpenGLRenderer(30591): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-02 10:16:18.041: W/OpenGLRenderer(30591): Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
02-02 10:16:18.069: D/OpenGLRenderer(30591): Enabling debug mode 0
02-02 10:16:19.237: I/System.out(30591): intent>>>>>>>>Intent { cmp=com.example.locato/.gotomap }
02-02 10:16:19.238: D/AndroidRuntime(30591): Shutting down VM
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591): Process: com.example.locato, PID: 30591
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.locato/com.example.locato.gotomap}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1761)
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1485)
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3778)
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3739)
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4049)
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4017)
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at com.example.locato.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:24)
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19761)
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
02-02 10:16:19.239: E/AndroidRuntime(30591):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
```

Breakpoint  doesnt even go to the send activity,,,
Application crashes while calling the intent...
Please do the needful...

Comment: remove `public gotomap(){}` from `gotomap` class. you should not create constructors unnecessarily.

Comment: Crashes with which exception? Please add the stack trace to the question.

Comment: also make sure that you defined the `gotomap` inside the manifest

Comment: I removed Public gotomap(){} but then too same error

Comment: Add your Activity to your manifest file "com.example.locato.gotomap"

Comment: Thanks SMR it workded...

Comment: Please check whether you have declared the gotomap.java in AndroidManifest.xml as an activity

Comment: `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.locato/com.example.locato.gotomap}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?` error itself says that you have to declare the `Activity` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file..

Comment: @NageshChinna Hey on suggestion for you improve your coding standard use java naming conventions like class name should be start Capital.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare your activity in manifest like:

```
<activity name="com.example.locato.gotomap"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to make sure the "gotomap" activity is defined in the manifest file. Second the activity class first letter should be capital. This is general Java standard.

```
 <activity
            android:name=".gotomap">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure each of your activity should be mention in manifest as bellow

```
<activity name="com.example.locato.gotomap"/> 

// use java naming conventions class name should be capital.
```

**Note: To improve your coding standard use java naming conventions like class name should be start Capital**

Answer (score 0):

Give the entry for gotomap.class in AndroidManifest.xml as an activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity android:name=".gotomap" />
```

add this to your manifest inside`<application>` tag